# Is it possible to track values in Adobe Marketing Cloud similarly to Google Analytic's event tracking values?

Tags: analytics, tracking, event-tracking

My company is using Adobe Marketing Cloud. We wanted to try and use analytics to log values like Google Analytics does it ([Google Analytics log values](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Values))

I have been reading thru the [documentation](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/en_US/documentation/analytics-reporting-1-4/whatsnew) and cant find anything similar. Does anyone of you know if it's possible to do this?